# File download: show checkbox to remember action if file is not a direct link

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer

[image]

See screenshot. When creating a direct link to a file to be downloaded, IE offers a checkbox to remember the setting.
When pushing a file to the client using a script, this checkbox never seems be shown.
Is there a way to force its visibility?

René

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without seeing your download script, but I'm pretty sure the checkbox gets shown when the MIME content type of the requested resource is something meaningful (e.g.`application/msword`).

My guess is that your download script serves `application/octet-stream` as the content type.

You would have to make your script serve `application/msword` as the content type.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not depend on the MIME type. I tried all kinds of variations including applictaion/msword: no checkbox.
The checkbox is there for direct links or when linking to an ASPS that redirects to the target file.
As soon as AJAX enters the ring it won't work: answer request with creation of a hidden iframe, put a form in the iframe and post --> no checkbox, although same MIME type and attachment in both cases.

Comment: @Krumelur how does the ASPS redirect to the target file?

Comment: It's in an AJAX environment. Therefore the client submits a form in a hidden iframe. The form's action is pointing to the file to download. Download is initiated but IE won't show the checkbox.

Comment: @Krumelur how about pointing to a script that does a `302` redirect to the download script? Maybe it has a problem with the URL being a form target